# Кнопка функции открытия веб-браузера

Tags: c++-cli

Как открыть веб-браузер по нажатию кнопки?

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сначала получаете строчку, в которой прописан обозреватель по умолчанию

```
string browser;
RegistryKey key;

try {
    key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"HTTP\shell\open\command", false);
    browser = key.GetValue(null).ToString().ToLower().Replace("\"", "");
}
finally {
    if (key != null)
        key.Close();
}
```

Затем вызываете

```
Process process = new Process();

process.StartInfo.FileName = browser;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "http://hashcode.ru/";

process.Start();
```

Все - на C#, перевод на С++ CLI - самостоятельно.

Comment: А не легче
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("Твой URL");
Это на С++ 
И за то спасибо!